# massive Excel info upload to MySQL through php primary keys

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I'm having this issue I have figure out a way to upload my data which is on .xls format and input the correct info on mysql. I'm using phpmyadmin and php to upload the file but right now I'm having trouble with primary keys... sorry I'm kinda new programming trough php, and I don't know why, once I define my primary key and the script send the data the primary key wont respect and don't assign the same id(primarykey) to the same value for example :

[image]

and my code to input data  is as follows :

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_con.php';
if(isset($_POST["submit_file"]))
{ 
    $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $file_open = fopen($file,"r");
    while(($csv = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ",")) !== false) 
    {
         $fecha= $csv[0]; 
         $tipo = $csv[1]; 
         $impresion = $csv[2]; 
         $hojas= $csv[3]; 
         $cadena_nombre = explode('(', $csv[4]);
         $usuario =$cadena_nombre [0];
         $usuario =$csv[4];
         $stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO trabajo 
                                    (fecha,tipo,impresion,hojas,usuario) 
                            VALUES(:fecha,:tipo,:impresion,:hojas,:usuario)");

        $stmt->bindparam (':fecha', $fecha);
        $stmt->bindparam(':tipo', $tipo);
        $stmt->bindparam(':impresion', $impresion);
        $stmt->bindparam(':hojas', $hojas);
        $stmt->bindparam(':usuario', $usuario);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

echo "CSV Imported Successfully";
?>
```

My DDL looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `trabajo` (
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `hojas` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `impresion` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `trabajo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`usuario_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `trabajo`
--
ALTER TABLE `trabajo`
  MODIFY `usuario_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=12592;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: You are getting `$cadena_nombre` and `$usuario_id` both from `$csv[4]` That does not look correct. Is it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly rigth I posted wrong code but still .... im not getting primary keys

Comment: So it would be good to see the right code,

Comment: @RiggsFolly done only usuario_id was wrong

Comment: Now `$cadena_nombre = explode('(', $csv[4]); $usuario =$cadena_nombre [0]; $usuario =$csv[4];` Or am I missing something here

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah it seems correct but i only want to know if there is a way to tell php to insert same data to une unique id there are a lot of registers and I must use PK to relate tables

Comment: So is `usario_id`  an autoincrement column?

Comment: @MewkOna show the DDL for your table(s) so we can figure out what you mean by primary keys ? Also, since your are using bindParam , you could toss the prepare and bind outside of the loop (after you cleared your key issue)

Comment: my DDL looks like this i hate updated my post :

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes usuario_id is autoincrement and indeed it is sending primary keys but as you can see USER_ID repeat the values many time and its not assigning the unique values

Comment: It looks like your table is a list of print jobs or something, where each user can be listed more than once.  So assigning a unique user id to rows in this table (instead of a unique print job id) seems wrong, as the same user might send print job 1 and print job 4.

Comment: @James I was wondering if I could considerate each user ID as primary key instead  of assigned a primary key of each register to make querys